# Finding disposable email addresses

Tags: api, email, disposable

I've been using undisposable.net's API to find disposable email addresses but noticed that the site no longer appears to be functional.

Anybody know what happened to them? Are there any other sites that provide an API to disposable email address domains or is there a list that can be downloaded to check against?

**EDIT: Clarification:** I don't want to create disposable email addresses. I want to check if an email address submitted on a registration form is disposable.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to check if an e-mail address is disposable, or a way to generate disposable e-mail addresses?

Comment: @Michael E - good question - the first - I'm looking for a way to check if an email address is disposable.

Comment: I'd think twice about letting a 3rd party know the email address of everyone that signs up to my website.

Comment: This isn't an answer; but really if people don't want to give you a 'real' email address, you're not going to get one and there's not much you can do about it.  I use disposable email addresses a lot, and I have a special 'real' email address that I never check for sites that demand it.  But it gets checked even less frequently than the disposable ones.

Comment: Please don't force people to register for things they do not want to register for. Downloads for example. If you force me to use a non-disposable emails I won't hesitate to send 15 minutes finding a disposable one you don't know about just for the sake of not giving you a real email address.

Comment: @ThiefMaster yeah but most people *won't* spend the 15 min, which is the whole point of a DEA list. It's a legit tool for sites *trying* to enforce a 1 account per user policy: https://gist.github.com/adamloving/4401361

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [nodisposablemail.com](http://nodisposablemail.com/) provides this service. It's got a free account for up to 500 lookups, and [pricing](http://nodisposablemail.com/products/) goes up from there.

**EDIT**
Thanks to @abrkn for pointing out that nodisposablemail.com is no longer active. Looks like there's an alternative at [block-disposable-email.com](http://www.block-disposable-email.com/), which is free for 200 queries ([pricing info](http://www.block-disposable-email.com/cms/about/pricing/) for beyond that).

Comment: Site no longer exists.

Comment: Hi there is also http://www.antideo.com to help identify disposable email addresses. Simple use `api.antideo.com/email/u3879025@mvrht.net` to see the result. Also they provide free and paid options

Answer (score 1):

The only one that I know of that provides excellent disposable email is this one but has no API but I can imagine it would be simple to check via issuing a 'POST' to it with a email address here...[Mailinator.com](http://www.mailinator.com/)

**Edit:** Thanks to ***cmptrgeekken*** for the heads up after his comment to this answer! My thoughts on this. I am not 100% sure nor confident if you can reliably check if the email address is a disposable one or not as they email address will appear to be perfectly legitimate and reasonable.... this may sound hackish but to go through all disposable email domain names to check, such as '@malinator.com'... again, this is muddy as perhaps there may be a header available in the email that could be checked against spamhaus.org to see if it's a disposable one...the bottom line, there is an '@' in the email, the domain will be valid and can telnet to it to check... other than that...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I think he's actually trying to find a site that determines if an email address is from sites like mailinator.com, to tell the user that they can't use that email address.

Comment: @cmptrgeekken: Oh ok....fair enough the question was not clear enough when I posted the answer! Thanks for the heads up...

Answer (score -1):

You can try jetable.org or yopmail.com