# Detect if an email domain is a disposable one

Tags: email, email-validation

Well I am using disposable emails like mailinator , guerilla , 10 minute mail and the like . But this type of email is not really reliable when it comes to production. I am thinking of blacklisting them all using reg ex, but that would be overkill I Guess... Is there any service that can help me in doing validations like this? As Far as I am concenrned I have used an app that doesn't allow that kind of email , I know it is possible , Any hints ?

Comment: Read [ask] and share your research. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380392/finding-disposable-email-addresses, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682141/is-there-any-possible-way-to-detect-a-disposable-email-address-dea-server, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900880/detect-if-an-email-domain-is-a-disposable-one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916266/filter-disposable-email-addresses-without-exposing-the-address-to-a-third-party, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366734/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-is-fake

Comment: If you don't want people to give you disposable or fake email addresses don't force them to give you an email address at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd find a list of the most common disposable domains and validate based on that list. A good starting list can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/adamloving/4401361

Comment: Exactly What I Need. Thank You!

Comment: No problem - have a good one.